# Project doesn't compiles with QtWebKit

Tags: qt5, qtwebkit

I want to build a small app with just a QtWebKit widget into my frame, but it's doesn't compile.

Here the errors:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebViewC1EP7QWidget'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QWebView6setUrlERK4QUrl'
```

It's a problem into the linking step, who said he doesn't find the reference to WebKit

But, I've included  and into the .pro file, I've added : QT += webkit

What can I do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the Qt 5 porting guide: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/portingguide.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We must to add this snippet too:

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```